# javascript or jquery identify if I am a popup

Tags: javascript, popup

is there any JS available to identify if I (the window) am a popup window?  Obviously this would need to be x-browser compatible.

And I realize this may not be foolproof in at least one way, i.e. that if Firefox opens a buch of windows that were previously open, the popups no longer are considered popups even if they look like popups :) I've tried...

Thanks

Comment: Why not try googling or SOing first before asking?

Comment: Define "popup window".

Comment: a window opened by javascript specifically using window.open() that wasn't opened before, and is not tabbed with the same window that opened it (as would normally be the case with target="_blank"

Answer (score 0):

try

```
if ( typeof(window.opener) != "undefined" )
{
   alert("I'm a new window");
   ...


}
```

Comment: window.opener will return null if its the main window in many browsrs, so the safe test should be if(window.opener)